# How to write Get query to get the correct Pricebookentry objects

Tags: rest-api, rest, workbench

Im rather new to SG and is trying to fetch some data.

What I want to do in a nutshell is fetch all the Pricebookentry that match a certain Pricebook2Id. I tried the below query for this on the workbench and it worked

/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Product2Id,+Product2.Name+from+Pricebookentry+WHERE+Pricebook2Id='01s2X000002X6PxQAK'

the issue is that I get a bad request (400) when I try to call this in my React component (I'm a front end dev). Below is the code.

```
const result = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url:
            'https://tahina-test2-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Product2Id,+Product2.Name+from+Pricebookentry+WHERE+Pricebook2Id=01s2X000002X6PxQAK',

        data: {
            fields: 'Name'
        },
        headers: {
            Authorization:
                '<redacted>'
        }
    });
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't post a bearer token on a public site. It is just as valuable as a password, and may compromise your account. I suggest deleting the session Id from setup as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi mate, thats was a mistake on my part. Thank you for the head up :) for now its alright since its a dummy app :) Would you be able to answer my question btw?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a payload here:

```
    data: {
        fields: 'Name'
    },
```

This is because you can't use GET with a HTTP Body.

Remove that and your code should work fine.

Edit:

Your query is also missing the quotes:

```
'https://tahina-test2-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Product2Id,+Product2.Name+from+Pricebookentry+WHERE+Pricebook2Id=\'01s2X000002X6PxQAK\'',
```

Comment: Afraid not, still get a 400 :/

Comment: @Kisho I see the quotes appear to be missing. Try that.

Comment: That was indeed the issue. I used backticks and added the Pricebook2Id in quotes as such- url: `https://tahina-test2-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/query?q=SELECT+Product2Id,+Product2.Name+from+Pricebookentry+WHERE+Pricebook2Id='01s2X000002X6PxQAK'`,   Thank you for you help :)

Comment: @Kisho glad to help!